# Is it possible to convert words stored in a matrix of N*1 into single sentence in R?

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a matrix of 1196*1 with each row containing one word. I need to write these words into a single sentence.

```
I  
Have  
A  
Matrix
```

Aim: `I Have A Matrix.`

Comment: Things may be possible or not based on the constraints you apply. You need to mention the code or design you have tried and challenges being faced in them

Comment: How do you decide on the full stop `.` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your matrix as a reproducible example:

```
my_matrix = matrix(c("I", "Have", "A", "Matrix"), ncol = 1)
```

Here is a method to make it a sentence:

```
> paste(my_matrix, collapse = " ")
[1] "I Have A Matrix"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `paste`

```
paste(df1$col, collapse=" ")
```

If it is a `matrix`, use

```
paste(df1[, "col"], collapse=" ")
```